# Excel Autofilter doesn't work on column with date and time with VBA code

Tags: vba, datetime, excel, autofilter

I'm having trouble when filtering date and time values together using VBA on MS Excel. When I need to filter only dates, I find no problem using the code below:

```
myRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
    ">=" & CDbl(CDate((Date - 2))), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & CDbl(CDate((Date)))
```

The question is: how could I specify a time when filtering? Example: I'd like to filter results from yesterday at 19:00 until today at 8:00.

Comment: You can add a TimeSerial() or TimeValue() function to the Date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a way:

```
Sub DateTimeFilter()

    Dim d1, d2, m1, m2, y1, y2 As Integer

    Dim dt1, dt2 As String

    d1 = Day(Date - 1)
    d2 = Day(Date)
    m1 = Month(Date - 1)
    m2 = Month(Date)
    y1 = Year(Date - 1)
    y2 = Year(Date)

    dt1 = m1 & "/" & d1 & "/" & y1
    dt2 = m2 & "/" & d2 & "/" & y2

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$3:$L$2012").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        ">=" & dt1 & " 19:00", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & dt2 & " 08:00"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub DateTimeMaker()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, MyRange As Range
    Dim crt1 As Double, crt2 As Double
    d1 = DateValue("6/24/2014") + TimeValue("19:00")
    d2 = DateValue("6/25/2014") + TimeValue("8:00")
    crt1 = CDbl(d1)
    crt2 = CDbl(d2)
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:C10")
    MyRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & crt1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & crt2
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To have the dates "float" use:

```
Sub DateTimeMaker()
    Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, MyRange As Range
    Dim crt1 As Double, crt2 As Double
    d1 = Date - 1 + TimeValue("19:00")
    d2 = Date + TimeValue("8:00")
    crt1 = CDbl(d1)
    crt2 = CDbl(d2)
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:C10")
    MyRange.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">=" & crt1, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & crt2
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks by the hint, @Gary, but I'm not working with static dates. I'll always need to work with a date range from yesterday at 19:00 until today at 8:00. Which syntax would work on this case?

Comment: it's still not working. I don't know if it changes from Excel version to version but I'm using MS Excel 2010.

Comment: What are your symptoms??

Comment: My data is in columns **A** thru **C** with *real* date/times in column **C** ..................make sure column **C** contains real values and not text.

Comment: The cells were supposed to be formatted as "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm". But even changing the format to "real date/time" it didn't work.
I don't know if this information helps, but my desktop date/time configurations are on the brazilian standard, so I use "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm" instead of "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm".

Comment: What do typical values look like if formatted as **General?**

Comment: They are shown as number. Example: 25/06/2014 02:39 is equal to 41815,11042.